# View multiple animated gifs at the same time?

Tags: windows, gif, animated-gif

I'm looking for a program/image viewer/gallery that I can point to a folder and see thumbnails of all the animated GIFs doing their animation.

Or something that make the GIFs animate without having to open each file.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 6):

Open notepad, put this text inside:

```
FOR /F %%G IN ('dir /B *.gif') DO echo ^<img src="%%G"^ width="40"^>^ %%G^<br^> >> gifs.html
```

Save it with name "whatever.bat" in folder where you have your gifs located, but choose "All files", not "Text file". Then navigate to your folder and doubleclick on whatever.bat. This will create another file called "gifs.html" in current directory. Doubleclick on it and you will see your gifs in web browser.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
I did everything you mentioned but when I doubleclick on whatever.bat nothing is happening...

Comment: oh wait this time I tried to save the whatever.bat with the encoding UTF-8. When I doubleclicked on it indeed created another file called gifs.html but when I doubleclick on this one it only shows a white page in the browser.

Comment: then you did not save whatever.bat to folder where you have gifs

Comment: I have six gifs in the folder where I saved whatever.bat

Comment: Try another browser. If it does not help, open gifs.html with notepad, copy content, put it to pastebin.com and put here link to it.

Comment: I tried 3 different browsers already and I just noticed the content of gifs.html is empty. I did the whole thing again but I still get the same result. Maybe there is something missing in the code you gave me? I am using windows 7 is that ok?

Comment: does the code work for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Problem was that i was trying it in command window, but in batch files those percent signs needs to be doubled, so % becomes to %%. I edited my code and simplyfied it for more readability. It should be working now.